# Problems with a relative url

Tags: jquery

I have a script which gets a url from a page in a website. Like so:

```
 var catHref = $(this).closest('[id]').children('a').attr('href');
//outcome is something like http://www.website.com/
```

After that I use this url to get some Json content. Like so:

```
 var url = catHref;

  $.getJSON(url, function (json){     
      ... etc ...
  }
```

The problem is that this url is not relative, so it is always http://. Firefox has very strict security. So when I request the Json on a https:// or secured page I always get an error. In Chrome and IE everything works fine. 
So what I try to do is convert this url to a relative one. Like so:

```
 var url = '//' + catHref.replace(/^https?:\/\/[a-z_\-\.]+?\.[a-z]{2,5}\//i, '');
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. It gives an url like:

```
https://http//www.website.com/
```

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url2 = url.split("/");
if((url2[0]==="http:")&&(window.location.href.split("/")[0]==="https:")){
    url2[0] = "https:";
    url = url2.join("/");
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4td/

Comment: Note that this will convert `http` to `https` when needed, but not `https` to `http`.

Comment: I was just typing about the "==="... haha! Ok this works perfectly. Thx for your answer!